# How to convert a rowversion in binary string format to byte array

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

i need to convert the string representation of `rowversion` column  in `sql server 2008`  to `byte` array using `c#`

```
String rowversion = "0x000000000001265E";
```

i want to convert this to `byte[]`

any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
String rowversion = "0x000000000001265E";
byte[] mybyteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(rowversion);
```

Comment: @Helen could you show us your code and what is the error? ad which stored procedure you talk about? please clarify your self

Comment: thanks   .  i got the result   with string rowversion = AAAAAAABJlw=     AND convert  that to byte[] mybyteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(rowversion);

Comment: This throw exception {"Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."}

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] chrArr = rowVersion.ToCharArray();

byte[] objBytes = new byte[charArr.Length];

for(int x=2;x<charArr.Length;x++)
{
objBytes[i] = (byte)charArr[x];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;    
byte[] RowVersionConverter(string rowVersion)
    {
       var value = ulong.Parse(rowVersion.SubString(2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
       return BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    }
```

This might work for you.  But I think it may well be in the reverse order of how SQL will expect it.  So you may want this:

```
byte[] RowVersionConverter(string rowVersion)
{
   var value = ulong.Parse(rowVersion.SubString(2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
   return BitConverter.GetBytes(value).Reverse().ToArray();
}
```